# Get Max Rate from users table and get the next 2 rows and previous 2 rows

Tags: sql, sql-server

If I have a users table contains a column called Rate
 and I need to get the maximum value from the rate column and name it position (position will be 1 for the max value only)
 after that I need to get a specific row by Id .
 and select the next 2 rows (next means the row's rate is bigger than the row I got) and previous 2 rows (rows' rate is smaller.
what is the query that can give me this result??

Ex:

| Id | rate |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 80 |
| 2 | 50 |
| 3 | 100 |
| 4 | 90 |
| 5 | 10 |
| 6 | 20 |

and I need to get row has Id 2,the result should be:

| Id | rate |
| --- | --- |
| 4 | 90 |
| 1 | 80 |
| 2 | 50<------------------> |
| 6 | 20 |
| 5 | 10 |

Comment: So this is two separate queries? One, get the ID of the max rate. Two, nothing to do with the first at all, retrieve ID X and also the 2 nearest rates to the rate of ID X ?

Comment: Where does `6 20` come from and what happened to `3 100`? I don't understand the logic

Comment: Please show what you have tried so far.

Comment: @Charlieface sorry I missed one row, I've edited the question , the row ```3  100``` shouldn't appear in the result, because I need to get the next 2 rows and previous 2 rows depending on the rate

Comment: So is it just that you want the two rows before and after the marked row, when ordered by `rate`? The top row seems irrelevant

Comment: Do I get an answer to my question?

Comment: @CaiusJard yes I need to queries

Comment: And they're nut related to each other in any way? You should ask two questions..

Comment: @CaiusJard actually they r related because I need to get a row by id and next 2 rows and prev 2 rows and the position(value 1 if the rate of the row was the max rate)  of each row, but if I got the two queries I can create a new query can do what I need

Comment: @CaiusJard exactly

Answer (score 1):

One option is literally just how it's written, unioned together:

```
select * from
(
  select top 2 * 
  from x 
  where 
    rate <= (select rate from x where id = 2) 
    and id <> 2
  order by rate desc
) lower

union all 

select * 
from x 
where id = 2

union all 

select * from
(
  select top 2 * 
  from x 
  where 
    rate >= (select rate from x where id = 2) 
    and id <> 2 
  order by rate
) higher
```

Comment: IMO remove the middle `union all` query, and remove one of the `and id <> 2` but not the other, and change one `top 2` to `top 3`. Also put `(select rate from x where id = 2)` into a variable, alternatively put it in an outer `from` and `cross apply` everything else

Answer (score 0):

A slightly more efficient version of @CauisJard's answer

- Get the `rate` of the row `id = 2` first
- Then `cross apply` everything else
- Combine the unioned queries so `id = 2` is retrieved with two others.

```sql
select
  data.*
from (
    select rate
    from x
    where id = 2
) StartPoint
cross apply
(
    select *
    from (
        select top (3) * 
        from x 
        where rate <= StartPoint.rate
        order by rate desc
    ) lower

    union all 

    select *
    from (
        select top (2) * 
        from x 
        where rate >= StartPoint.rate
          and id <> 2 
        order by rate
    ) higher
) data;
```